# Is the margin parameter of ConstraintLayout.connect() in pixels or dp?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm guessing pixels, but [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#connect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) doesn't specify px or dp.

Comment: It's pixels. If you want to check, you could look at the code or you can do a test. Define a layout with two widgets with a margin set using "dp" such as "50dp". In code, maybe after a delay, set the connection to 50 using "connect()" to see if it jumps to a narrower margin. (It will.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixels. (thanks @Cheticamp)

As far as I know now, all Android and AndroidX Java APIs use pixel units unless explicitly specified.